# Why does JavaScript code execute faster over time?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, v8

I've got this problem I have been working on and found some interesting behavior. Basically, if I benchmark the same code multiple times in a row, the code execution gets significantly faster.

Here's the code:

http://codepen.io/kirkouimet/pen/xOXLPv?editors=0010

Here's a screenshot from Chrome:

[image]

Anybody know what's going on?

I'm checking performance with:

```
var benchmarkStartTimeInMilliseconds = performance.now();
...
var benchmarkEndTimeInMilliseconds = performance.now() - benchmarkStartTimeInMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the execution sees a jump in speed after the third iteration in each browser.

Comment: Google "just in time" compilation/optimization.

Comment: Just like fine wine...gets better with age (supposed to anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome's V8 optimizing compiler initially compiles your code **without optimizations**. If a certain part of your code is executed very often (e.g. a function or a loop body), V8 will replace it with an **optimized** version (so called "on-stack replacement").

According to https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/06/08/what-does-v8-do-with-that-loop:

> V8 always compiles JavaScript to native code. The first time V8 sees a
>   piece of code, it compiles it quickly but without optimizing it. The
>   initial unoptimized code is fully general, handling all of the various
>   cases that one might see, and also includes some type-feedback code,
>   recording what types are being seen at various points in the
>   procedure.
>
> At startup, V8 spawns off a profiling thread. If it notices that a
>   particular unoptimized procedure is hot, it collects the recorded type
>   feedback data for that procedure and uses it to compile an optimized
>   version of the procedure. The old unoptimized code is then replaced
>   with the new optimized code, and the process continues

Other modern JS engines identify such hotspots and optimize them as well, in a similar fashion.